# How to save input from TextEdit field into a string?

Tags: android, string, addtextchangedlistener

I'm making a simple app, where there is one TextInput field and a button next to it.
The TextInput field loads @string/duration_time from strings.xml.
The button next to it will display a simple message ("hello" + the string duration_time). However, it will always display the original information from string duration_time.

How do I set up a TextChangedListener to update the string/duration_time to reflect the input from the user? How do I access the information from TextInput and use it? Because as in the example below, under "public void afterTextChanged" I am trying to save the information, but I don't know where it's stored.

Kind regards

```
button2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String duration_input= WHAT_Do_I_Put_Here;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are using editText and button as Android Wigets.
Now if you want to get the the text inside editText on click of button.It can be done like this

```
String textEdit = "";
button.setOnClickListener(->view{
    textEdit = editText.getText().toString();
});
```

Now your textEdit will contain the text which you entered in your editText.